# Android market buyer informations

Tags: android, google-play

If you have an app posted on Android Market, which isn't free, so the user needs to pay a fee to download it. Do you as the seller see any information referring to the users who bought the app? An email address or something. A way to possibly contact them after the fact. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you sell apps you have access to the Google Checkout page, in which you see all the transactions with details about the buyers.

The contact email given for the buyers usually is an email address generated by Google Checkout (something like name-x87jkl00od@checkout.google.com). And you should only use that address for stuff regarding the purchase, and absolutely not for advertisement. (for each buyer you can see whether they allow advertisement to be sent to them or not).

Comment: I see. But can i send them a message even if they don't allow advertisement? Or does that block every incoming message? (And no, i don't want to send advertisement :) )

Comment: I think there's nothing that will block that email. But probably if users report that as spam your account might be blocked.

Comment: OK, so just to clear things up before i accept your answer. I CAN contact users after they have bought my app, for other purposes other than advertisement or spamming or things like that...

Comment: Yes it should be fine. (here's the google checkout help: https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=132606 although it doesn't say much).

Comment: and this is still valid with the new arrangement of the Android market....cause now it's google play .... :(